# How to prevent a QLabel from expanding because of added text?

Tags: qt, qlabel, qtwidgets, qsizepolicy

There is a QLabel added to the status bar of the main window. When setting a long text, the QLabel expands and expands the window with it. It is necessary that the size of the QLabel and the window do not change, and only the text that fits is shown (as happens with a fixed size widget).

The width of the QLabel cannot be fixed, because it must change depending on the width of the window. Probably there are some size policy settings for widgets?

I tried setting a fixed width and different size policies.

Comment: I don't understand. QStatusBar doesn't normally resize the window even when its internal widgets require more space (no matter if they were added through `addWidget()` or `addPermanentWidget()`). Are you sure that you're not trying to set the size policy of the status bar, possibly with a `Preferred` horizontal policy? That's the only thing I can think of that could eventually do what you describe, and it's obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `QSizePolicy::Ignored` for the label's width, and set its stretch factor to 1 in the layout:

```cpp
statusTextLabel->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);

ui->statusbar->addWidget(statusTextLabel, 1); //stretch must be set
```